Boy comes alone to dangerous city and cries himself to sleep
This particular scene entered my head the other day and I can't figure out where it's from.
As best as I can recall, a young boy/man (maybe late teens or early twenties) comes alone to dodgy area of a city. All I can guess is that it was New York, but assuming that is the case I can't think if he came from another part of the US or another country. He finds an apartment, either from looking around or from having called about it earlier, and it's really run down with people yelling and fighting. Feeling very unsafe from the people outside still yelling, he barricades the door and lies on the bed and either keeps his eye on the door or forces himself to sleep.
My best guess for time period is 80s/90s.

I'm afraid this sounds like a very common scene that might appear in many movies. Do you remember anything else? What the plot was about, the genre, what the boy looked like, the possible actor playing him, other scenes?

That's all I can really recall. But even if some possible films were listed I might be able to identify it.

The thing is, M&TV.SE isn't a forum. Asking for lists is considered off-topic and ID answers that are mere guesses are discouraged. But well, maybe someone would know exactly what you're talking about, who knows. Good luck!

You may be talking about the movie "Big", starring Tom Hanks as the adult version of a boy who suddenly grew up after a magical wish. About half an hour into the movie, his friend (who's still a kid) and he find Tom Hanks a seedy hotel room in a scary city. There are the sounds of fighting outside as Tom curls up on a bed, scared and crying. It happens at 1:17 in this clip.

That's it! Thank you so much, that was killing me.

The way you described it made me picture that scene in the movie immediately! Thanks for the up-vote and for marking my answer as The Answer. :)
